Does “top” use a different convention than “ps” to list process priority?
I run a program with chrt --rr 99 ./profiler and list its priority with ps and top. I'm getting different numbers, see PID 3095853 below:

139 - vs rt -20. What is the reason? Is it a new vs old convention?
Is there an API call to get PR? I'm getting NI with getpriority() and would like to have a similar way to get PR.
